# How to get the checkout status of a sharepoint file over REST API

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint

How to get the checkout status of a file (and the user how locks the file) on Sharepoint via REST API?

With `http://site url/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/file name')/CheckOut()` and `http://site url/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/file name')/CheckIn(...)` I can check out and check-in files. But if a file is already checkout or not checkout I got expected HTTP error 423.

It is possible to ask the Sharepoint about the checkout status of a file before I call checkout/checkin?

Thank you
Andreas

Answer (score 2):

You could use the CheckOutType property for the file to get the checkout status.

```
If CheckOutType = 0, the file is Checked Out
If CheckOutType > 0, the file is NOT Checked Out
```

And you could get the CheckOutType property like this:

```
http://site url/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name/file name')?$select=CheckOutType
```